# Family Networks at Living DNA tells me to Keep Fishing?

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, living-dna

Late last year (8 months ago) I accepted an offer via FindMyPast to upload my AncestryDNA results to Living DNA.

Three months later I followed the instructions in an email from Living DNA to opt-into its Family Networks.

Now 6 months later my Family Networks page says that I should:

> Keep Fishing!
>
> We haven't caught you any matches yet

At AncestryDNA I match to 329 4th cousins or closer and my ancestry is 75% English, 12.5% Welsh and 12.5% Scottish so I thought Living DNA would show me quite a family network of matches.

Is Family Networks expected to show 0 matches for someone like me?

Comment: My only matches are family members I uploaded myself. 100% English ancestry.

Comment: LivingDNA's database right now is much smaller than any of the other  consumer-facing genealogy dna testing sites; plus their users have to explicitly opt-in to matching, so most people have a very small number of matches if any. I'm told it was very similar in the early days at other sites...

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl I think there's enough in your comment to make a minimal length answer.

Comment: I'm not sure it would be any better than yours.

Comment: I am in the same matchless situation, five months after uploading. On Ancestry I see new low-grade matches every day. On LivingDNA, not one fish. I do wonder how Findmypast feel about this - they've been pushing LivingDNA as their DNA solution for a while now, and it doesn't seem to have generated much success.

Comment: I will say that I only tested at LivingDNA to get the detailed regional breakdown on UK ancestry, and have been very pleased with it -- some of it led me to go: spot on. And some of it led me to go -- hmm -- haven't found that in my tree yet, but I do have some branches not yet leafed out.  But, really, no way am I an Essex girl! Except, it transpires from some recent breakthroughs that I do indeed have unexpected ancestry in Hertfordshire and Essex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a page on the Living DNA site which was posted about June 2019 titled [Why I have not got any matches with Living DNA but do elsewhere?](https://support.livingdna.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028682611-Why-I-have-not-got-any-matches-with-Living-DNA-but-do-elsewhere-)

> With the large majority of our customers only testing at Living DNA
>   (due to our rigorous European data laws) and many choosing not to
>   upload their data to other sites, we've already had numerous people
>   find close relatives who were not on other platforms. Our database is
>   also growing all the time with 50,000 more people having opted in
>   since the beginning of the year.
>
> Therefore, while you may not have many matches today, or even in the
>   coming months, we really do encourage you to have your DNA on our
>   platform and keep checking back for when more matches appear.

It seems like I am now ready to be matched, and I just need to wait for more tests to be taken and uploaded at Living DNA before the odds start to favour one of them matching me.